# Sencha Touch - display button underneath template

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to create a panel from a template using the Sencha Touch 2 framework but I'm having a little trouble.  What I'd like to do is display the HTML template followed by a button underneath - an example of this using HTML instead of a template would be:

```
Ext.define('GS.view.Home', {

extend: 'Ext.Panel',

config: {
    title: 'Home',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: [
                '<img src="resources/images/someImage.gif"/>',
                '<h1>A Header</h1>',
                "<p>some text</p>"
            ].join("")
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Click Me',
            ui: 'forward'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Which looks like this when rendered:

[image: button on bottom]

What I'd like to do is load a panel using a template instead but still have a button underneath.  My code currently looks something like this:

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<img src="resources/images/someImage.gif"/>',
    '<h1>A Header</h1>',
    '<p>some text</p>',
    {
        // XTemplate configuration:
        compiled: true
    }
);
Ext.define('GS.view.Home', {

    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'home',
    config: {
        title: 'Home',
        tpl: tpl,
        data: [],
        items: [

            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Click Me',
                ui: 'forward'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

But this results in the button being placed above the template HTML:

[image]

I've also tried adding a panel to the items array with the tpl value set to the template but this results in no HTML being rendered at all.

**Anyone know how I can use a template but still have a button at the bottom?  If your answer is to just include a button with the correct class name into the template html then how do I link it back to the controller? (I'd usually use the itemId config property).**

Cheers,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between your two approaches: the first one has a panel, that contains a pannel with the html, and the button.. The second one has a panel that contains both the html and the button (and I guess then sencha puts the html under the button).

Using two panels in the bottom solution should do the trick:

```
Ext.define('GS.view.Home', {

    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'home',
    config: {
        title: 'Home',
        items: [
           {
               xtype: 'panel',
               tpl: tpl,
               data: [],
            },

            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Click Me',
                ui: 'forward'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - I think that's basically one of the approaches I was saying I'd tried - adding a panel to the items array and using the tpl.  The reason I can't get this approach to work is because this view is called from a controller (a controller of a list view) as the result of clicking an element in a list.  I then pass the list data into this view like so:   this.getMain().push({
   xtype: 'detailsview',
   data: record.data
  }); does that makes sense?  So I don't know how to populate the data attribute if I use a panel in the items array like in the above example.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that part. The "correct" way would be to use a store. But I'd be the first to admit that that complicates things and is overkill in most situations. There are two ways how to "hack" it: first push the view, then get a reference to the panel (just give it an id, and get it with Ext.getCmp(id) -- there are other ways as well if you run in to duplicate id's as well) and use setData(), or 2) add an applyData() function in your view that sets the data to the sub-panel instead of the main panel. Personally I would prefer the latter approach. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Cool - thanks Claude.  I'm looking at using a store now - makes more sense.  Thanks again